# Additional data in ajax POST when sending file

Tags: jquery

My question is, if there exist any solution for sending some kind of data(for an example string), beside formData? For an example, to add something to `data` parameter.

Current data parameter looks like this:

```
data: form,
```

I wish to send additional string, something like:

```
data: {someValue: 'something', file: form}
```

Is possible to achieve this somehow, because I need to send some string also.
(I do not wish to add additional parameter to url like "?site=example").

Current code:

```
variables.ajaxVar = $.ajax({
    url: '../../bh-api/?action=archiveUpload',
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){
            myXhr.upload.onprogress = progress;
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    success: function (res) {
        console.log(res)
    },
    data: form,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append parameters to the form data object

```
form.append('someValue', 'something');
```

Comment: you mean form.append(...)?
but in this case, how can i grab this value in php? because $_POST is empty somehow...

Comment: @Klemzy that should  work. `$_POST['someValue']` should give you `something`

Comment: I tryed but $_POST variable is totally empty. I can find file parameter inside $_FILES variable, but someValue is not part of this $_FILES.

Comment: Ok, @Musa, it works now, sorry :) Probably I have done something wrong before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May not be what you're looking for but you can add an `<input type="hidden">` field to your form and store your data there?